# FirebaseAnalyticsを使うと、使うなというエラーが、使わないと、画面指定してないというエラーが出ます。

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase

## 問題点

FirebaseのAnalyticsを使ったコードを実行したところ、次の様なエラーが表示され、画面が表示されませんでした。

```
2020-04-26 19:59:56.713197+0900 ShrineApp2[3548:1604575]  - <AppMeasurement>[I-ACS036001] Analytics screen reporting is disabled. UIViewController transitions will not be logged.
2020-04-26 19:59:57.123631+0900 ShrineApp2[3548:1604575] 6.22.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023007] Analytics v.60401000 started
2020-04-26 19:59:57.124085+0900 ShrineApp2[3548:1604575] 6.22.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023008] To enable debug logging set the following application argument: -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled (see http://goo.gl/RfcP7r)
2020-04-26 19:59:57.143741+0900 ShrineApp2[3548:1604588] 6.22.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS800023] No pending snapshot to activate. SDK name: app_measurement
2020-04-26 19:59:57.156748+0900 ShrineApp2[3548:1604588] 6.22.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023012] Analytics collection enabled
```

## 試したこと

私のinfo.plist内で、FirebaseScreenReportingEnabledを逆にYESに設定したところ、以下のエラーが表示され、画面が表示されませんでした。

```
2020-04-26 20:12:53.585528+0900 ShrineApp2[3552:1609111] 6.22.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS031025] Analytics screen reporting is enabled. Call +[FIRAnalytics setScreenName:setScreenClass:] to set the screen name or override the default screen class name. To disable screen reporting, set the flag FirebaseScreenReportingEnabled to NO (boolean) in the Info.plist
2020-04-26 20:12:53.610520+0900 ShrineApp2[3552:1609111] 6.22.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023007] Analytics v.60401000 started
2020-04-26 20:12:53.610666+0900 ShrineApp2[3552:1609111] 6.22.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023008] To enable debug logging set the following application argument: -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled (see http://goo.gl/RfcP7r)
2020-04-26 20:12:53.635436+0900 ShrineApp2[3552:1609114] 6.22.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS800023] No pending snapshot to activate. SDK name: app_measurement
2020-04-26 20:12:53.649835+0900 ShrineApp2[3552:1609115] 6.22.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS800023] No pending snapshot to activate. SDK name: app_measurement
2020-04-26 20:12:53.661723+0900 ShrineApp2[3552:1609111] 6.22.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023012] Analytics collection enabled
```

どの様にすればエラーを消せるでしょうか、ご教示お願いします。

最初に表示するViewControllerのコードは以下の通りです。

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UINavigationController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }


    @IBAction func managerLogin(_ sender: Any) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "managerlogin", sender: nil)
    }

    @IBAction func createAcount(_ sender: Any) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "create", sender: nil)
    }

    @IBAction func userLogin(_ sender: Any) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "userlogin", sender: nil)

    }
}
```

Comment: 最初のログは今現在 _Analytics screen reporting_ が無効であることを報告しているだけで、エラーではありませんね。2番目のログは現在、それが有効になっていることの報告でこれまたエラーではありません。よーく探せばこれらのログを出力されないようにできるかもしれませんが、それらはエラーでも何でもないので、「画面が表示されませんでした」とは関係ないと思われます。あなたの目的は「そのようなログ出力が行われないようになること」ですか、それとも「所望の画面を表示すること」ですか?

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。「所望の画面を表示すること」です。is inithal View Controllerは指定してあります。